# Identify distributions within a mixed set

Tags: distributions, bayesian, clustering, exponential-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I am looking for a way to identify possible distributions within a set of data points.

- assuming I have a `1-dim` mixed vector of points $d_j$ within $[0; 300]$
- the points can be from different distributions for example:

  - `log-normal distribution` with $LN  (10, 0.5)$
  - `exponential distribution` with $\lambda = 0.6$
  - other distributions like `Erlang` (or `Gaussian`) [spec. it is about durations of failures]

My aim is to tell if the data points are from one distribution or maybe from two different. But so far I faced some problems for which I am looking for help:

- if the distributions overlap, some common clustering algorithms fall short, here I tried using mode detection (`LPMode`) but I am not sure if there might be a better way
- can I take advantage of the fact that I can restrict the choice of distributions to choose from?
- I had a look into `AutoClass` and was wondering if there are some advances in the Bayesian methods I should have a look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EM principle can be applied to other distributions as well, not only with Gaussian Mixture models.

It will give you a goodness of fit (how well the data is explained), so this may serve as a starting point for evaluating the match. You probably want to also require each distribution to account for, e.g., 10% of the data at least, to avoid false results that just capture some small 'bump' rather than a separate distribution.

It may be worth exploring robust estimators instead of MLE if you assume the data to be dirty.

Comment: Ok but now I have two more questions: 2) will this even work on `1-dim` data, because every example so far mentions `multi-dim`. And can this be used to identify different distributions? Maybe I am misunderstanding sth but I have only encountered EM to look for multiple distributions of the same type; not a mixture of different distributions
EDIT: found an example using a mixture of `gaussian` and `exponential` - so this is clear

Comment: Yes, it will work on 1-dimensional data. Just use a univariate distribution instead of a multivariate distribution.

Comment: But it would require me to know the type of distributions involved a priori or test everything and do a goodness-of-fit evaluation, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. It's one dimensional, meaning it's fairly manageable. Try different candidates, keep the best.